# Synology diskstation - alternating drive backups

Tags: backup, synology

At our job site, we have a Synology Diskstation (DS412+) serving as our backup device. It currently backs up our ESX host and mail server. We also have an external drive backup in place for off-site backups.

There's currently two USB hard drives used to accomplish this off-site backup. One drive is left connected to the device and the backups run in the early morning. The other drive is taken off-site.

This has worked great, but ever since *both* drives were connected at one time (to recover data), it's become difficult to manage. Now, the drives appear as "usbshare1" and "usbshare2". Before, one drive or the other would be "usbshare1"; now, this doesn't happen so we can't have a single backup job since it'd fail when drive 2 was connected but drive 1 was not.

What do people usually do in this case? I've attempted to alternate days, but this would require changing the backup schedule weekly and I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a workaround in case anyone else runs into this issue:

It looks like the count is based on the number of drives connected and will take the first available number, so what I did was this:

1. Disconnected drive 2 (`usbshare2`)
2. Connected a spare USB drive I had laying around (format does not matter)
3. Disconnected drive 1 (`usbshare1`)
4. Connected previously drive 2.

At this point, drive 2 was now `usbshare1` as desired. To avoid this from occuring, don't connect both drives at the same time. If both drives must be connected for some reason (like restoring from a backup), this process can be repeated.